# Как получить элемент после отображения / инициализации?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Есть классы `droppable` и `droppable.shut`, которые отвечают за отображение новости:

```
<div id="{{news.newsId+'expandItem'}}" class="droppable">
    <small ng-bind-html="getComment2(news.news)"></small>
</div>
```

Внутри функции происходит проверка на достаточный объем и если он больше нужного, то к классу droppable прибавляется `.shut` и меняются стили (добавляется возможность скрытия и пр.):

```
angular.forEach($scope.companyNews, function (newsExtended) {
...
    if(numOfRows > 6 || numOfRowsInReport > 6){
                        newsExtended.isToExpand = true;
                        $timeout(function() {
                            $('#' + newsExtended.newsId + 'expandItem').addClass("shut");
                        }, 100);
                    }
...
}
```

Проблема в том, что без таймаута такая логика не работает, т.к. элементы не успевают инициализироваться, а решение с таймаутом костыльное и бросается в глаза, если смотреть на конкретно блок с текстом во время загрузки страницы.

Предполагаю, что можно получить элементы после инициализации посредством jQuery или каким-нибудь другим способом, но не знаю как.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто вычислите необходимые параметры, запишите в "новость" и примените в [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```js
angular.forEach($scope.companyNews, (newsExtended) => {

  newsExtended.numOfRows = ...; // 7
  newsExtended.numOfRowsInReport = ...; // 7
  newsExtended.isToExpand = ...; // true

});
```

```html
<div
  id="{{news.newsId+'expandItem'}}"
  class="droppable"
  ng-class="{'shut': (news.numOfRows > 6 || news.numOfRowsInReport > 6 || news.isToExpand)}"
>
  <small ng-bind-html="getComment2(news.news)"></small>
</div>
```

<sub>И вот так `ng-bind-html="getComment2(news.news)"` не надо делать. Даже в старом добром [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) есть компоненты (или директивы, на худой конец), так что лучше вынести в компонент, поставить логику в контроллер, шаблон в шаблон...</sub>

Comment: Странно, ответ принят и вроде вопрос решён, но нет взаимных плюсов. То есть, ТС считает: "Ответ как-то помог, но в обшем от него мало пользы",  а автор ответа считает: "Вопрос в целом неинтересный и малополезный, но дам уж ответ".  Это так?

Comment: @0xdb смешная ситуация. Не, я ничего такого не имел в виду, плюсик накинул :)

Comment: @0xdb автор ответа действительно так считает, без обид, Revasha. объясню: во-первых это - вопрос по технологии, которая давно и прочно ушла в категорию legacy, во-вторых - даже в рамках технологии это очень beginner-ский вопрос. Так что пользы для базы знаний тут нет, просто помощь коллеге, который, кмк, поддерживает проект на устаревающей, [пока] не знакомой технологии :)

Comment: @0xdb, в твоём мире это - как вопрос про firebird 2

Comment: @nörbörnën Ну не стоит считать, что те, кто поддерживает старые проекты - невезучие по жизни. Новые проекты после ввода через 2-3 года уже не на новейшем уровне, а служат по 20-30 лет. firebird2 это 2006. Пару лет назад мигрировал данные с самописной БД написанной на ассемблере в начале 1970-ых, и она работала и для неё была группа поддержки.

Comment: @nörbörnën beginner-ский вопрос - это очень относительно. Когда-то сам тратил дни на поиск ошибки, которую теперь найду за минуты, ну так что? Ну или например, посмотри на SO, что там вопросы с1000+ голосов, совсем не  beginner-ские?